# Semop: Invalid argument

Tags: c, semaphore, invalid-argument

I have this code that basically makes a P on the semaphore with number `sem`. The semaphore is in a pool. The problem is that sometimes I get `Invalid argument` and I can't figure out why.

```
bool sem_p(key_t key, int sem){
    int semid = semget(key, sem, 0666);
    struct sembuf sb = {sem, -1, 0};
    if(semop(semid, &sb, 1) == -1){
        perror("sem p"); 
        printf("sem %d\n", sem);
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

When that function gets called, it prints

```
sem p: Invalid argument
```

Comment: The semaphore set doesn't exist, or semid is less than zero, or nsops has a nonpositive value. Read the manual :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko Semid returns success, what else should I check?

Answer (score 2):

Check if

```
int semid = semget(key, sem, 0666);
```

returns success or failure.  As @VladLazaranenko mentioned there could be a lot of possible errors.  Check every single return code for every single function you call (if they return a value) - for production systems.

Comment: Also, continually calling `semget` is almost certainly unnecessary.  Once you have the semid, you have the semid.

Comment: Semid returns success, what else should I check?

Comment: @Duck I agree.  But this is the only code I can see.  If you make a call then check the return code.  To the OP: review your code and make sure there are no error return codes. And you check return codes.  That will eliminate a lot of possible causes.